# Unity C# - Gun fires too fast after clicking multiple times quickly and then holding down left click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am currently trying to make a 2D WW2 game using unity, I am making a shooting system but I have a problem, right now, if the player holds down left click they will auto fire, but for some reason if you click multiple times really quickly and then hold down left click, instead of firing at the usual pace the gun does, it fires really fast. Please help me I am still very new to unity and have only been doing it for 1.5 years.

Code:

```
public float AutoFireDelay = 0.4f;

public bool isFiring = false;

 private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        isFiring = true;
        StartCoroutine(DelayCoroutine());
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        isFiring = false;
        StopCoroutine(DelayCoroutine());
    }
}

public IEnumerator DelayCoroutine()
{
    while(isFiring == true)
    {
        Shoot();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AutoFireDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much Unity, but I *suspect* you're creating a new co-routine on each update, so you'll have lots of them running effectively concurrently.

Comment: The coroutine returns an id of the instance of itself running. If you dont stop that instance its not stopping anything. You could call stop all coroutines as a lazy answer or keep the handle and call stop on the handle. Which is the proper way

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a series of coroutine when you click it multiple times.
so therefore your problem happened.

Here is a code snippet how it should works. :D

have fun!

```
 public float AutoFireDelay = 0.4f;
    public bool isFiring = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && !isFiring)
        {
            isFiring = true;
            print("shoot it !");
            StartCoroutine(Shotcoolddown());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Shotcoolddown()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AutoFireDelay);
        isFiring = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the issue is not that using single clicks you can fire faster than the auto-fire (as addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76472051/7111561))

The issue is rather that afaik

```
StopCoroutine(DelayCoroutine());
```

doesn't work that way. Since it returns a new instance of `IEnumerator` the one you originally started continues to be executed.

You rather need to store and then stop the same instance like e.g.

```
public float AutoFireDelay = 0.4f;
public bool isFiring => fireRoutine != null;

private Coroutine fireRoutine;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        fireRoutine = StartCoroutine(DelayCoroutine());
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        if(fireRoutine != null) StopCoroutine(fireRoutine);
        fireRoutine = null;
    }
}

public IEnumerator DelayCoroutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
       Shoot();
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(AutoFireDelay);
    }
}
```